# How to play video dynamically when its source is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I have got a

```
<input type="file" id="howtovideo" name="howtovideo" accept="video/mp4"> </span>
```

When its changed , i am calling the below function to play video dynamically

```
$("#howtovideo").on('change', function() {
    loadVideo();
});

function loadVideo(){
    alert('loadVideo called');
    var newsrc = 'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4';
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    var source = document.createElement('source');
    source.setAttribute('src', newsrc);
    video.appendChild(source);
    video.play();
}
```

But nothing is happening and there are no errors in console [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/157/).
Could you please let me know how to play vdeo dynamicaly ??

Comment: Add `autoplay` attribute to video tag.

Comment: add your video element to the dom before you invoke `play()`. Or use the `autoplay` attribute on the video element

Comment: even though adding autoplay  is not solving the issue

Comment: Why you append new `source` tag to video? Only change `src` attribute of current `source` tag.

Comment: Thanks Mohammed , Could you please provide a sample fiddle of doing this rightly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add new `source` tag. Only set address of new video to `src` attribute of current `source` tag. Note that after changing `src`, you need to load video using [`.load()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) and then play video. Also if you have jQuery, use it to finding elements.

```js
$("#howtovideo").on('change', function(){
    loadVideo();
});

function loadVideo(){
    var newsrc = 'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4';
    $('#video > source').attr('src', newsrc);
    $("#video")[0].load();
    $("#video")[0].play();
}
```

Comment: but could you please why the error in console Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined